# Map camera image onto sphere

Tags: python, spherical-geometry, mercator

How would I determine what the red point `(phi', theta')` is for a camera oriented at a known `(phi, theta)` is from a given image?

[image]

The point of this is to determine what `(dphi, dtheta)` is so that I can rotate my camera to that location.

I was thinking of a equirectangular or Mercator projection, but couldn't quite figure out how to convert map image coordinates to `(phi', theta')`.

Comment: careful, latitudes increase (absolute value) with distance to the equator! what software are you using? three.js for example offers fairly easy methods to orbit a camera around a sphere.

Comment: I'm working in a Python environment.

Comment: Lightweight Python wrapper for Cesium.js https://github.com/sinhrks/cesiumpy

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized it's actually for a custom language with no library support.